# What stability guarantees are given for WildFly configuration?

Tags: java, configuration, wildfly

An important part of the JavaEE platform is backwards compatibility, but I'm curious what that entails for configurations. I'm especially interested in the standalone.xml configuration for WildFly; can I expect the options in it to be stable across versions of WildFly? Or maybe just parts of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WildFly team tries to keep the configuration compatible or offer a migration tooling (for example when moving from jboss-web to undertow). If you're concerned about long term stability then maybe you should use Red Hat JBoss EAP which is a productized version of WildFly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the [migration tool](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/CMTOOL/JBoss+Server+Migration+Tool+User+Guide) as my guideline I think :)

Answer (score -1):

I think so, but you need to be up to date on each version, with the new releases. The standalone.xml file is updated with a lower frequency than the own server implementations, its base is practically the same since our old JBOSS. I've been using wildfly since its early versions and never had backward compatibilite issues.

What I see happening a lot is that most of the developers do not know the dependencies that the server implements and end up having problems in deploy, jar hell and problems in rutime due to lack of knowledge of the dependencies.

In my opinion widfly is the best server full JavaEE, but there are things I think are bad, one of them is the use of CXF in webservices. Do not worry about standalone.xml, I have not seen to add any feature to cause compatibility issues.

Comment: Not sure but I think JBoss Windup helps you migrate your application.

Comment: Yes, you're right, very cool, I did not know this tool, I always did everything at hand, thank you.